# how to make dynamic option label html

Tags: jquery, html

Aye sir, i want to make option like "916812 - Kurt Cobain", and when i click it shown only "916812" and i have done with that..

but when i want to reselect the option "916812" to others it didnt change back to "916812 - Kurt Cobain". How to solve this? here is my code :

HTML :

```
<body>
<select name="anggota_nis" id="anggota_nis">
<option hidden selected value=""></option>
<option value="916812">916812 - Kurt Cobain</option>
<option value="918291">918291 - Freddi Mercury</option>
<option value="912728">912728 - Gerry Cherone</option>
<option value="991829">991829 - Axl Rose</option>
<option value="927182">927182 - Steven Tyler</option>
<option value="912728">912739 - Russel Hitchcock</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Jquery :

```
  $("#anggota_nis").on('change', function(){
      var nis = $("#anggota_nis").val();
      $("#anggota_nis option[value="+nis+"]").text(nis);      
  })
```

jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/he7Laytg

[here's the form i created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7dqM.jpg)

So, basically i want to make user feel helpfully because when searching "student name" is based on "NIS" which is only number value from option.

I think its kinda hard searching the "student name" only with the "ID" so i put "student name" with it.

Comment: Before you change the text, set a `data()` field to it's old value.  When you change it, find all the elements with that data field, and restore them.  But, also at the same time, why do you want to do this?  This is a very strange user interface...

Comment: @Taplar so its not good for user interface? because i think its helpfully for user than only showing the value like "916812" and when user choose the name "Kurt Cobain" showing in the new input text

Comment: The question doesn't show the *"Kurt Cobain" showing in the new input text* part, so all I see is you removing part of their select.  Even if you show it in another field, your changing the data out from under the user, which is weird.  However, that's my personal opinion.  You can do what you want with the first part of my suggestion.

Comment: ok @Taplar thanks for suggestion.. i will try that, sorry if my english messed up but i need to try for solving my problem :-)

Comment: fyi, i edited my question for more reason to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//take note of the data-name attributes added to the options
//bind a change event listener to the select
var $anggotaNis = $('#anggota_nis').on('change', function(){
  $anggotaNis.find('.changed') //find the previously changed option
    .removeClass('changed') //remove the class, as we are reverting them
    .text(function(){ //set the text back, based on the value and name
      return this.value +' - '+ this.getAttribute('data-name');
    });
  
  $anggotaNis.find(':selected') //find the option just selected
    .addClass('changed') //add the class to mark that we are changing it
    .text(function(){ //set the text to just the value
      return this.value;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="anggota_nis" id="anggota_nis">
<option hidden selected value=""></option>
<option value="916812" data-name="Kurt Cobain">916812 - Kurt Cobain</option>
<option value="918291" data-name="Freddi Mercury">918291 - Freddi Mercury</option>
<option value="912728" data-name="Gerry Cherone">912728 - Gerry Cherone</option>
<option value="991829" data-name="Axl Rose">991829 - Axl Rose</option>
<option value="927182" data-name="Steven Tyler">927182 - Steven Tyler</option>
<option value="912728" data-name="Russel Hitchcock">912739 - Russel Hitchcock</option>
</select>
```

Comment: wow sir, thats awesome like i want to do.. thank you very much im so helped sir :-)